# how to read space before string using scanner in java?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;  

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         int x=sc.nextInt();

         Double y= sc.nextDouble();
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
       String name = sc1.nextLine();


        System.out.println("String: "+name);
         System.out.println("Double: "+y);
         System.out.println("Int: "+x);
}
}
```

input : (before 'ram' have 5 space)

`343434343`

`343.434343`

`ram   sdf`

Expected output :(before 'ram' have 5 space)

`ram   sdf`

`343.434343`

`343434343`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create two scanners. Also, you'll need to do `nextLine()` once you read the double.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    Double y = sc.nextDouble();

    /* Note the change here */
    sc.nextLine();
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("String: " + name);
    System.out.println("Double: " + y);
    System.out.println("Int: " + x);
}
```

Output:

```
String:      ram sdf
Double: 343.434343
Int: 343
```